# Multiple hostnames require a unique iframe for each URL

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Rather than create many swat sets in STAT to migrate each unique iFrame to a multi-tiered environment, I want to create a javascript that calls the correct iFrame based on the hostname and migrate all iFrames to every environment in a single swat.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function selectiFrame() {
if (window.location.hostname == "padv.abc.com") { 
document.getElementById("padv").style.display="block";}
else {if (window.location.hostname == "paqa.abc.com") { 
document.getElementById("paqa").style.display="block";}
else {if (window.location.hostname == "pacp.abc.com") { 
document.getElementById("pacp").style.display="block";}
else {if (window.location.hostname == "papd.abc.com") { 
document.getElementById("papd").style.display="block";}
}
}
</script>

<body onLoad="selectiFrame();>

<iframe id="padv" src="padv.html" frameborder="0" height="1px" width="1px" scrolling="no">
<p>Your browser or device does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

<iframe id="paqa" src="paqa.html" frameborder="0" height="1px" width="1px" scrolling="no">
<p>Your browser or device does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

<iframe id="pacp" src="pacp.html" frameborder="0" height="1px" width="1px" scrolling="no">
<p>Your browser or device does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

<iframe id="papd" src="papd.html" frameborder="0" height="1px" width="1px" scrolling="no">
<p>Your browser or device does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

Any help to make this code workable is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

How about just:

Script:

```
var i = document.getElementById('pad');

switch(window.location.hostname) {
   case 'padv.abc.com':
       i.src = 'padv.html';
       break;
   case 'paqa.abc.com':
       i.src = 'paqa.html';
       break;
   etc...
}
```

HTML:

```
<iframe id="pad"></iframe>
```

Comment: Let me give it a try Marc, I appreciate your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a bracket or two....

This is what you should have:

```
function selectiFrame() {
    if (window.location.hostname == "padv.abc.com") {
        document.getElementById("padv").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        if (window.location.hostname == "paqa.abc.com") {
            document.getElementById("paqa").style.display = "block";
        } else {
            if (window.location.hostname == "pacp.abc.com") {
                document.getElementById("pacp").style.display = "block";
            } else {
                if (window.location.hostname == "papd.abc.com") {
                    document.getElementById("papd").style.display = "block";
                }
            }
        }
    } // was missing
} // was missing
```

---

Better way with `else if`:

```
function selectiFrame() {
    if (window.location.hostname == "padv.abc.com") {
        document.getElementById("padv").style.display = "block";
    } else if (window.location.hostname == "paqa.abc.com") {
        document.getElementById("paqa").style.display = "block";
    } else if (window.location.hostname == "pacp.abc.com") {
        document.getElementById("pacp").style.display = "block";
    } else if (window.location.hostname == "papd.abc.com") {
        document.getElementById("papd").style.display = "block";
    }
}
```